# MySQL Partitioning by Year and Week

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I want to use mysql partition tables to partition a table into YEAR and the WEEK number. I know exactly how to do this with mysql merge tables but partition tables are different. Can someone please help with the following table schema?

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateandtime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `othervalue` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Also does it have to be in a certain engine?

And if I store the dateandtime as a int(10) timestamp how would I do it?

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateandtime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `othervalue` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.1 cannot do partition by date, so you must you workaround... Usually you partition by function `TO_DAYS(dateandtime)`, for example like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
... ) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(dateandtime)) (
 PARTITION pNULL VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20111218 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-12-18')) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20111225 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-12-25')) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pNew VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB
)
```

I defined here 4 partitions - the first is just for sake of completeness, so that insert of date in future won't fail. (You can't INSERT a value for which a partition does not exist.) The first partition is for performance - NULL values will be petentionally stored there. The middle 2 partitions are actually being used, each keeping one week of data.

You can drop old partition (this is very fast compared to just DELETEing old rows) using `ALTER TABLE tbl DROP PARTITION xyz`. You can add new partitions by splitting the last partition:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl REORGANIZE PARTITION pNew INTO (
  PARTITION p20120115 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-01-16')),
  ...
  PARTITION pNew VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Comment: dateandtime needs to be part of the PRIMARY or UNIQUE key right?

Comment: no... I use for logging tables which have 12+ millions rows per day, so also many rows within the same second, so UNIQUE would not be possible in my case.